# Getting rancid/clogin to work in spite of banners filled with #-marks?

Tags: rancid

I have thousands of switches where the company banner proudly flies in ASCII art made exclusively of #-marks.

This, according to [the rancid FAQ](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/FAQ), is a show stopper:

```
Q. Are there any characters in the banner that rancid has problems with OR  
 I changed the device's command prompt and now collection is failing?  
A. The trickiest part about clogin (et al) is recognizing the prompt  
 correctly.  clogin looks for '>' and '#' to figure out if it is logged  
 in or in enable mode.  So if you have a '>' or '#' in your login banner  
 (or other motd), then clogin gets confused and will not be able to log  
 in correctly, and thus rancid will fail.  

 Don't use '>' or '#', or whatever the termination character of the given  
 device's prompt is, in your prompt or in your banner or other motd.
```

Obviously, I can't change all of the banners. Even if I could, I'd have used `clogin`, soooo...

Has anyone hacked together a workaround for this?

If it helps, in my case there banner lines all start with at least three spaces.

Comment: You should consider moving this to http://stackoverflow.com/ - The reason I have suggested this is because I have made modification to rancid and it's made from Bash and Perl scripts so you could probably achieve what you desire by changing the part that looks for `'#'` or `'>'`. Create a regex or similar that looks for `'*#$'` (which is pseudo regex by the way!). I'm trying to suggest there `'anything before a # then end of line'`.

Comment: That is possibly wrong as I just gave it off the top of my head, but what I am trying to suggest is that you could probably create a little bit of logic to solve this problem in code.

Comment: @jwbensley - I put it here because it's a specific network tool - if it doesn't take, I'll dig into the code myself and post my shortcomings on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I think your best chance actually is the rancid-discuss mailinglist (http://www.shrubbery.net/mailman/listinfo/rancid-discuss)

Comment: There was a post on this 9 days ago; http://www.shrubbery.net/pipermail/rancid-discuss/2013-December/007353.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in upstream and is no longer relevant. I am closing it.